# Dapper Multi Mapping

Tags: c#, dapper

I've got an object:

```
public class Species : IEntity<int>
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public SpeciesCategory Category { get; set; }
     public WetlandIndicator WetlandIndicator { get; set; }
}

public class SpeciesCategory : IEntity<int>
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WetlandIndicator : IEntity<string>
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Designation { get; set; }
     public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I use Dapper to call the following query:

```
SELECT 
    [Species].*, 
    [SpeciesType].*, 
    [WetlandIndicator].Code AS Id, 
    [WetlandIndicator].Designation 
FROM 
    ((([Watershed].[Vegetation].[Species] INNER JOIN [Vegetation].[SpeciesCategory] 
        ON [Watershed].[Vegetation].[Species].[SpeciesCategoryId] = [Vegetation].[SpeciesCategory].[Id]) INNER JOIN [Watershed].[Vegetation].[SpeciesType] 
        ON [Watershed].[Vegetation].[Species].[SpeciesTypeId] = [Vegetation].[SpeciesType].[Id]) INNER JOIN [Watershed].[Vegetation].[WetlandIndicator] 
        ON [Vegetation].[Species].[WetlandIndicatorCode] = [Vegetation].[WetlandIndicator].[Code])
```

I receive the make sure when using multi-mapping, make sure you use the `splitOn` attribute.  Which I am, but I still receive the error.  So I assume I have some type of usage error or syntaxtual error. The code that continually errors is as follows:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SpeciesDomain>> GetAllSpecies(string query) =>
        await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Species, SpeciesCategory, WetlandIndicator, SpeciesDomain>(query, (species, speciesCategory, wetlandIndicator) =>
        {
            species.SpeciesCategory = speciesCategory;
            species.WetlandIndicator = wetlandIndicator;
            return species;
        }, splitOn: "Id, Code");
```

Important Note:  By default Dapper utilizes Id, which is why I renamed Code to Id, but even with Code or the rename I still receive a multi-mapping error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to remove the 'Code' from splitOn: "Id, Code". Your query renames it to "Id".

Dapper also uses "Id" as a default, so no need to specify.

> Dapper is able to split the returned row by making an assumption that
>   your Id columns are named Id or id. If your primary key is different
>   or you would like to split the row at a point other than Id, use the
>   optional splitOn parameter.

Below is a quick test to verify:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=foo"))
{
    var result = conn.Query<Species, SpeciesCategory, WetlandIndicator, Species>(
        "select Id = 11, Name = 'Foo', Id = 22, Name = 'Bar', Id = 33, Designation = 'House Cat' ", 
        (species, speciesCategory, wetlandIndicator) =>
    {
        species.Category = speciesCategory;
        species.WetlandIndicator = wetlandIndicator;
        return species;
    }).First();

    Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(11));

    Assert.That(result.Category.Id, Is.EqualTo(22));
    Assert.That(result.Category.Name, Is.EqualTo("Bar"));

    Assert.That(result.WetlandIndicator.Id, Is.EqualTo(33));
    Assert.That(result.WetlandIndicator.Designation, Is.EqualTo("House Cat"));
}
```

**Update to demo split by different fields and types**

```
public class Species
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SpeciesCategory Category { get; set; }
    public WetlandIndicator WetlandIndicator { get; set; }
}

public class SpeciesCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WetlandIndicator
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=foo"))
{
    var result = conn.Query<Species, SpeciesCategory, WetlandIndicator, Species>(
        "select Id = 11, Name = 'Foo', Id = 22, Name = 'Bar', Code = 'X', Designation = 'House Cat' ", 
        (species, speciesCategory, wetlandIndicator) =>
    {
        species.Category = speciesCategory;
        species.WetlandIndicator = wetlandIndicator;
        return species;
    }, splitOn: "Id, Code").First();

    Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(11));

    Assert.That(result.Category.Id, Is.EqualTo(22));
    Assert.That(result.Category.Name, Is.EqualTo("Bar"));

    Assert.That(result.WetlandIndicator.Code, Is.EqualTo("X"));
    Assert.That(result.WetlandIndicator.Designation, Is.EqualTo("House Cat"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I found out the primary reason it failed.  Dapper didn't like the `splitOn` parameter alternating between `int` and `string`.  By forcing all of them to be unified it worked.  The other item I noticed, is that if you have a column called `Code` for instance, which mirrors a primary key but SQL isn't set to a relational identifier it will also error.

After those were rectified it pulled no problem.

Comment: Just to clarify for others: Dapper does not fail if you use fields of different data types to split by. I will update my answer to demo.

Comment: I need to clarify, if you have field: 'Code' and an Id column called 'Code` issue.